# How to make Spark dataframes to have values even for next execution of code

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am creating several Spark Dataframes using IntelliJ IDE but for every execution of the code, they are getting created afresh which is making the code to run for long time.

So even for a minor change in the code, I am forced to execute the whole code again and again.

**Is there any way to hold or cache the Spark Dataframes for use until the IDE is active ?**

Comment: You can cache your data inside your job so that it's not read in a couple of times among transformations/actions, but once you exit your job - it has to load your data once again.

Comment: Thanks @ALincoln . But can you please explain little more about your answer. Sorry that as I am a Spark Newbie, it will be more helpful if you mention in detail

Comment: I was talking about caching in Spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching

For your test in IDE - I just recommend either reducing the size of your data to load faster in IDE and/or customize memory settings for your IDE. Usually it's good to use small datasets for local tests before running Spark on cluster with huge datasets.

Answer (score 0):

[Dataframe caching](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching) is useful to speed up access to a dataframe which is being used often in the code.

However, for this case, it wouldn't solve his problem because everytime the code is run, he generates a new dataframe (If I'm not mistaken). He would still need to run the query again. But he wants to hold it in the IDE level. **I do not think there's a way to do this.**

Comment: So If a dataframe is used frequently within the code, then caching will be useful otherwise it is not useful right ?